# Выделяется ли запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Но это не совсем классическая музыка() в нашем понимании.

Ставится ли запятая? Если да, то почему?
Есть ли здесь зависимость от контекста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: "Но это не совсем классическая музыка в нашем понимании".

Выражение " в нашем понимании" в качестве вводного слова применяется редко, хотя тематически близко к вводным словам (в нашем понимании -  с нашей точки зрения).

В предложении чаще всего играет роль  обстоятельственного определения, тесно примыкающего к определяемому слову, и поэтому не обособляется, например:Мораль в нашем понимании начинает складываться в период распада родоплеменного строя.

Для обособления требуется особая позиция, например: Это, в нашем понимании,не совсем классическая музыка. Также: Это, в нашем понимании, не учебный курс, а нечто другое.

Comment: Особая позиция внутри предложения?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Оборот должен как бы нарушать естественные синтаксические связи между словами в предложении, тогда его приходится относить на второй план интонационно, а на письме выделять запятыми.

Comment: Тут дело даже не в том, что это вводное слово или нет. "Классическая музыка в нашем понимании" - здесь " в нашем понимании" является несогласованным определением в нормальной позиции после определяемого слова. Любая другая позиция (перед определяемым словом или на расстоянии от него) - это инверсия, обычно ведущая к обособлению.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.